# SPF and OpenDMARC not working in Postfix

Tags: centos, email, postfix, email-server, spf

I am working on implementing SPF and OpenDMARC/DKIM to my mail servers.
Currently I have two mail servers in different subnets, each with separate DNS server and domain name. They can exchange emails successfully.

I set up SPF with pypolicyd-spf, DMARC with OpenDMARC and DKIM with OpenDKIM.
DKIM works flawlessly, but I have some issues with DMARC and SPF, probably they are related to my topography (a graph of it is placed below).

I have users made on each mail server and I exchange mails between them via Squirrelmail.

How to make SPF and DMARC work? In my email headers I get:

```
Received-SPF: None (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=192.168.22.132
Authentication-Results: OpenDKIM; dmarc=none (p=none dis=none) header.from=another.com
```

I think there is something wrong with that localhost IP in logs but I have no idea what causes it:

```
policyd-spf[2183]: prepend X-Comment: SPF check N/A for local connections - client-ip=127.0.0.1; helo=[192.168.22.128]; envelope-from=centos1@example.com; receiver=<UNKNOWN>
postfix/smtpd[2177]: D5DA9C0F5F38: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

my `postconf -n` output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd 
$daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = $myhostname
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.22.0/24
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:8893
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf, permit_mynetworks, 
reject_unauth_destination
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Network graph:

[image: network_graph]

I can provide any additional info if needed.

Of course all entries in DNS are made.

```
example.com.     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx ~all"
default._domainkey      IN      TXT     ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; "
          "p=XXXkeyXXX" )  ; ----- DKIM key default for example.com
_dmarc.example.com.       IN      TXT      "v=DMARC1; p=none; pct=100"
```

policyd-spf logs:

```
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "request=smtpd_access_policy"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "protocol_state=RCPT"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "protocol_name=ESMTP"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "client_address=192.168.22.132"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "client_name=gateway"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "reverse_client_name=gateway"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "helo_name=example.com"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "sender=daniel@example.com"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "recipient=marek@another.com"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "recipient_count=0"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "queue_id="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "instance=a73.5fe8c4e7.510b9.0"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "size=935"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "etrn_domain="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "stress="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "sasl_method="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "sasl_username="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "sasl_sender="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "ccert_subject="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "ccert_issuer="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "ccert_fingerprint="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "ccert_pubkey_fingerprint="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "encryption_protocol="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "encryption_cipher="
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: "encryption_keysize=0"
policyd-spf[2681]: Read line: ""
policyd-spf[2681]: Found the end of entry
policyd-spf[2681]: Config: {'Whitelist_Lookup_Time': 10, 'skip_addresses': '127.0.0.0/8,::ffff:127.0.0.0/104,::1', 'Reason_Message': 'Message {rejectdefer} due to: {spf}. Please see {url}', 'PermError_reject': 'False', 'Header_Type': 'SPF', 'TestOnly': 0, 'SPF_Enhanced_Status_Codes': 'Yes', 'TempError_Defer': 'False', 'Lookup_Time': 20, 'debugLevel': 4, 'Authserv_Id': 'centos2.another.agh.edu.pl', 'Mail_From_reject': 'Fail', 'Hide_Receiver': 'Yes', 'HELO_reject': 'Fail', 'Void_Limit': 2, 'Mock': False}
Dec 27 12:31:19 centos2 policyd-spf[2681]: Cached data for this instance: []
Dec 27 12:31:19 centos2 policyd-spf[2681]: skip_addresses enabled.
Dec 27 12:31:29 centos2 policyd-spf[2681]: spfcheck: pyspf result: "['None', '', 'helo']"
Dec 27 12:31:29 centos2 policyd-spf[2681]: None; identity=no SPF record; client-ip=192.168.22.132; helo=example.com; envelope-from=daniel@example.com; receiver=<UNKNOWN>
Dec 27 12:31:29 centos2 policyd-spf[2681]: spfcheck: pyspf result: "['None', '', 'mailfrom']"
Dec 27 12:31:29 centos2 policyd-spf[2681]: None; identity=mailfrom; client-ip=192.168.22.132; helo=example.com; envelope-from=daniel@example.agh.edu.pl; receiver=<UNKNOWN>
Dec 27 12:31:29 centos2 policyd-spf[2681]: not peruser
Dec 27 12:31:29 centos2 policyd-spf[2681]: Action: prepend: Text: Received-SPF: None (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=192.168.22.132; helo=example.com; envelope-from=daniel@example.com; receiver=<UNKNOWN>  Reject action: 550 5.7.23
```

Comment: What are your SPF & DMARC records (in the DNS zones for example.com and the other domain)?

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer my question. Your headers suggest you don't have SPF and that your DMARC policy is `p=none`, so you can't just say your DNS is ok.

Comment: Sorry, I have added my DNS records for SPF, DKIM and DMARC. From what I have know, p=none means that DMARC does nothing to the mails even if they do not passed authentication, so that is probably not a cause of my problem

Comment: It’s important to understand that DMARC *uses* SPF and DKIM authentication results. So you need to have a component that inserts an `Authentication-Results: yourserver.com; spf=…` header that OpenDMARC can then consume.

Comment: The problem is with my policyd-spf. I have added policyd-spf logs with debug_level=4 to my question. I can see that "client_name" and "reverse_client_name" value is "gateway" and "client_address" is an IP address of my gateway. Should it be like this or something is wrong?

Comment: It turned out that when sending from centos1 to centos2, sender's IP is somehow lost in router and the receiver acts as if the mail was sent from his gateway address. Is there any way of changing this bahavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of struggling with SPF by pypolicyd-spf, I have finally get to know what is wrong.

My topology included 2 DNS servers and my /etc/resolv.conf files on mail servers had both DNS servers.

OpenDMARC SPF worked like a charm and responded to the changes of spf records on both DNS, but pyspf did not.

The answer is: pypolicyd-spf does not support two dns in resolv.conf.
A simple workaround is to make two zones in one DNS server. Then suddenly pyspf starts working.